# Method to find smallest value of $x$ for which $x^2-x+C$ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, quadratics, factoring

**Problem statement:** Given the function $f(x)=x^2-x+C$, where $x$ is a positive integer $>1$ and $C$ is a positive integer ($C=0$ is also allowed), find some method and/or set of rules to always find the smallest value of $x$ that will give a non-prime number for the function $x^2-x+C$.

To show the research that has been formulated so far, I have denoted these set of rules for the problem:

- If $C$ is an even number, the smallest $x$ value for a non-prime is $2$ because the function will always give a non-prime when $C$ is even.
- $x^2-x+C=x(x-1)+C$, this shows $x^2-x$ is always divisible by at least $x$.
- If $x=C$, then $x$ will result in a non-prime but isn't always the smallest non-prime.

The last bullet point here provides an initial method for when C is odd - it allows one to narrow their search for smallest values down to $C \geq x\geq 2$. Lastly, here are a few that have been completed for example:

- When $C=3$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $3$
- When $C=5$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $5$
- When $C=7$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $2$
- When $C=9$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $3$
- When $C=11$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $11$
- When $C=13$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $2$
- When $C=15$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $3$
- When $C=1$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $1$
- When $C=0$ the smallest $x$ for $f(x)$ that gives a non-prime is $2$

Comment: You seem to assume that $C$ is positive in your bounds $2\leq x\leq C$...

Comment: @Servaes Have edited the post, thank you for the comment. Minor error on my part.

Comment: I don't quite understand; are there restrictions on $C$? Does it need to be at least $2$?

Comment: @Servaes The only restrictions on $C$ are that it has to be a positive integer, $C=0$ is also allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is even then $f(2)$ is not prime, and if $C=1$ then $f(4)$ is not prime. So suppose $C>2$.

Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $C$. Then $p$ also divides $f(p)$, so $f(p)$ is not prime unless $f(p)=p$. But this is the case if and only if $C=p(2-p)$, which is impossible as $C$ is positive. Hence $2\leq x\leq p$.

Alternatively, as $f(x)>1$ and $f(x)$ is increasing for $C>2$, you could try to find the smallest composite $D>C$ for which
$$x^2-x+(C-D)=0,$$
has integer roots. This is the case if and only if the discriminant is an integer square, that is, if and only if $1+4(D-C)$ is a square. So look for the least composite $D>C$ for which $1+4(D-C)$ is a square.

Comment: Can you clarify some sort of method that would allow one to look for the least composite $D>C$? If $C$ becomes a large positive integer, let's say $189$, then I imagine that just guessing numbers will make it hard to find some number for which $1+4(D-C)$ is a square.

Comment: Well you could start from the smallest, and work your way up. I doubt there is a very straightforward and direct method in general, there will most likely be some trial and error involved.

Comment: Do note that it could be easier to keep a list of values $k$ for which $1+4k$ is square. It starts with $k=2,6,12,20,30,\ldots$. Then you can check whether $C+k$ is composite for these $k$. But this is precisely brute-forcing the original problem.

Comment: Admittedly it would be disappointing if no method besides brute-forcing exist to solve this problem, but it appears that you are unsure if a more direct method exists. I will keep this question open for a bit longer, and if a better method does not come up then I will accept your method as the best way to find the smallest non-prime. Your method does provide a way that involves less trial and error than originally.